# Difficulty in web scraping some information after br tag not picked with python beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

so i have been trying to web scrape a public web directory https://www.kenyaplex.com/business-directory/?start=1&categoryid=286 to get contacts of companies. My code works well but its not picking information after the br tag for example it doesn't pick the email in the below details of the beautiful soup

```
<div class="c-detail">
<a href="https://www.kenyaplex.com/business-directory/86129-water-well-drilling-rig-gujarat-india.aspx">water well drilling rig, Gujarat, India</a><br/>+91-9825005407<br/>info@dhirajrigs.com</div>,
```

i have tried to change the index of the list but its not working,i have attached image of what the code i have is giving me.
i want it to pick both the phone number and the email but it either picks phone number or email where both are listed
the code am using is this below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

#DEFINING THE FIRST WEBPAGE
num = 1
#STRING FORMATTING THE URL TO CAPTURE DIFFRENT PAGES
url = 'https://www.kenyaplex.com/business-directory/?start={}&categoryid=286'.format(num)
#DEIFING THE BROWSER HEADERS SO THAT CAN WORK ON IT WITHOUT ERRORS
headers = {'User-Agent':'Chrome'}
records = []
while num < 100:
    url = 'https://www.kenyaplex.com/business-directory/?start={}&categoryid=286'.format(num)
    time.sleep(1)
    num += 30
    response = requests.get(url,headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
    company_info = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'c-detail'})
    print(company_info)
    #EXTRACTING SPECIFIC RECORDS    
    for name in school_info:
        Name_of_The_Company = name.find('a').text
        #Location_of_The_School = name.contents[2][2:]
        Contact_of_The_Company = name.contents[3]
        Email = name.contents[4]
        
        
        
        #converting the records to a tuple
        records.append((Name_of_The_Company,
                        #Location_of_The_School,
                        Contact_of_The_Company,
                       Email))
#EXPORTING TO A PANDAS FILE    
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns = ['Name of The Company',
                                      #'Location of The School',
                                      'Contact of The Company',
                                     'Email'])
df.to_csv('boreholes.csv', index = False, encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get telephone numbers and emails, you can extract the `<a>` tag from the details and then just get whole text -> split it -> do basic filtering with list comprehensions.

For example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.kenyaplex.com/business-directory/?start=1&categoryid=286'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

records = []
for detail in soup.select('.c-detail'):
    a = detail.select_one('a')
    name, url = a.text, a['href']
    a.extract()
    contacts = detail.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|')
    phones = [c for c in contacts if '@' not in c]
    emails = [c for c in contacts if '@' in c]
    records.append([name, url, phones[0] if phones else '',  emails[0] if emails else ''])


df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns = ['Name of The Company',
                                      'URL',
                                      'Contact of The Company',
                                     'Email'])

df.to_csv('data.csv', index = False, encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Saves `data.csv` (Screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thank you Andrew

Comment: It is working well for the first page, but am trying to iterate over many pages as i had done and its bring issues when add the while loop.Please if you can just patch the iteration for many pages too

Comment: I have sorted it out sorry, it was a small issue i had not seen